# Socket Programming: Delay

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I have a server app written in C# for Windows. I have a client app for android. I want to send data continuously from client to server in an infinite loop. The data is being sent but sometimes, there is a bad delay. I'm really stuck at it. Here's my client side code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            while(true) {
                try {
                    socket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
                    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                    out.println(msg);
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Any idea why is there a delay?

Comment: How bad a delay? Where is the server? Maybe it's your network or the internet routing.

Comment: Sometimes the communication is smooth. Sometimes, the message is received after a delay of up to 5 seconds. If you say, I'll attach server side code too.

Comment: I didn't necessarily want to see the server code, just give us information on where your server is. Is it plugged into the same network you're developing on? Is it at work, is it in another country?

Comment: It's in the same network. Server is in my PC, client is in my android phone. Both are on same network.

Comment: first I suggest you refactor your code like Knossos said. Then put  `Thread.sleep(1);` in the while loop and see if there is still a delay.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are initializing the socket every single iteration of your while loop.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        while(true) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println(msg);
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Refactor it out of the loop, like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = new Socket(IP, PORT);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        while(true) {
            try {
                out.println(msg);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        socket.close();
    }
}).start();
```

Unless that is by design, in which case, why?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. But in that case, only the first message was received at server. By first message, I mean the value of 'msg' in first iteration.

Comment: Does it help if you flush the PrintWriter after sending the data? `out.flush();`

Comment: **socket.close();** is unreachable. If i remove that, and use out.flush(), still the effect is same. Only first message is received.

Comment: Is that code in a Service? What are you trying to achieve? Flooding the Server with whatever `msg` is at the moment? Delays can have many reasons. The way you coded it, I could imagine local ports aren't freed fast enough ...

Comment: This code is in onCreate of my Activity. I'm trying to send the current x y z values of device's accelerometer to server.

Comment: @Fildor And I feed the updated x y x into the 'msg'.

Comment: Maybe you better start a Service for doing this. Not sure about the behavior of a Thread started in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is correct. The lag may be caused not only by the application but also by the network status.

Try to ping to the router from both devices and see if you are having lag spikes due to the wireless conection. If you see high lag in pings the problem is in the connection, not in the application.

Comment: I pinged the server from client and maximum time was 54.5 ms.